# Is there a way to generalize programming language syntax

Tags: programming-languages

I'm hoping to develop language independent tool for code analyzing. in order to do that i need  to find a way to generalize programming languages syntax. I thought of develop a layer between source code and analyzer so that it can understand the source code independent of the language.
I need to know is there a special research area for this problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: afaik there is no standard for pseudo-code, the problem is that programming languages differ way to strong (functional, oop, ...) which makes it practically impossible to create a pseudo language that can represent all of them

Comment: Extended Backus Naur Form?

Comment: Generalizing *syntax* is easy, it's called Grammar Recognition/Generation.  Generalizing language ***semantics*** is incredibly hard (maybe impossible).  And syntax is meaningless without the semantics to go along with it.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the kind of analysis you're going to do. If you want to analyze the "intent" of the code in a manner that is explainable in the context of the source language, the problem is likely impossible unless you restrict yourself to a particular language family (e.g. Java, C#, and C++, but even that is limited).  You can gain more flexibility if you're only interested in basic analysis, e.g. building a model of defined types and methods/functions.

If you're interested in analyzing low-level behavior, your best bet may well be to analyze the output of early stages of the compiler. For example, there are many useful types of analysis, such as data flow analysis, that can be done on Java bytecode, irrespective of the language that generated it. Similar analyses can be done on LLVM intermediate code or GCC's intermediate language (in fact, these compilers both do a lot of their optimizations on the intermediate code or assembly code level and are thereby able to do a lot of the same optimizations no matter what language is being compiled).

Answer (score 0):

In my research group, people have been working on an software analysis platform called [Moose](http://www.moosetechnology.org/). They thus developped the [Famix](http://www.moosetechnology.org/docs/famix) model to abstract over the syntax of specific languages. There are various importers from specific languages to the language-independent model.

There are common constructs that you find in many object-oriented programming languages with different syntaxes, e.g. inheritance, etc. It is however impossible to have a unique model that captures the semantics of all construct of all language--the model captures the semantics of common constructs shared by many languages.

Answer (score 0):

For static analysis you'll need "generalised" operational semantics, which has absolutely nothing to do with syntax. You're lucky - it does exist, because each and every practically useful language out there ends up being translated into semantics of the actual hardware.

Therefore, assembler of your CPU is exactly your "generalised semantics". Operational semantics of CPUs is a well-research topic, you'll find a wealth of papers if you dig deeper.

LLVM is low level enough to cover most of such semantics while being more compact and easier to analyse than the real hardware, so you may consider using a similar intermediate representation. SSA form can simplify the analysis significantly.

But do not get too excited - it is exceptionally hard to do any *useful* global analysis on such a low level - a generic memory model will require too much resources, rendering any analysis unrealistic on a contemporary hardware.

If you're ready to limit your choice of source languages severely, you can go up a level, and employ more analysable semantics. You may find [K framework](http://k-framework.org/index.php/Main_Page) interesting if you want to go this way.